# WebSite Javascript Search Engine

Tags: javascript, search

I'm looking for any javascript library that i can use to search content on my website, i have came across quiet a few but mostly they require the use of a database to store indexes for optimizing search queries, but i only need a database free search engine built in with javascript. can anyone direct me to the right location(url) where i can download it and install it on my website, which is build on a cakephp framework. Was thinking of a search engine that could index every new page a include in my website maybe once a night and then when i search it should output the search results on the separate page and with links to the actual pages where the keyword was taken from.

Happy new year and have a splendid year ahead..

Comment: I think zend lucene does not use data base, it just uses file system directly.

Comment: Can you explain **why** you want to do this in JavaScript?

Because It sounds like you want to keep a server-side index (*"index every new page [...] once a night"*, *"links to the actual pages"*). But JavaScript is primarily a client-side language that is run in the confines of a single page. Granted, [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) runs server-side, but you say you're using CakePHP... So I'm left wondering what your reasoning is.

Answer (score 0):

I bet your mistaken about JavaScript. In order to search, you will be needing records coming from the users which will be stored in the database so basically, you will be dealing with server side languages not JavaScript. JavaScript is only used for client-side which doesn't have to do anything with the database (Not unless your using Node.js).

Answer (score 0):

Both JavaScript and the browsers have come a long way. You could use [Lunr](https://github.com/olivernn/lunr.js) or [search-index](https://github.com/fergiemcdowall/search-index). Both can run in the browser. For search-index you use localStorage as the index. That means your data is stored per domain, in the browser. Nothing to install, nothing to maintain. And low server requirement since it's all happening on the client side.

Lunr is more mature and quicker to get up to speed, but search-index is maybe more feature rich?

Comment: Not fully sure how Lunr does things. Memory or localStorage? Maybe [Oliver Nightingale](http://stackoverflow.com/users/603187/oliver-nightingale) can answer that?